# Can this parser (concerning about infinite hierarchy of operators) be implemented purely in ReadPrec?

Tags: parsing, haskell

In Haskell, I tried to implement a parser for expressions containing [hyperoperations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperoperation), and finally succeeded. Valid expressions shall contain:

- Parentheses.
- Nonnegative integers.
- Addition represented by `+`. It has precedence of 6, and its associativity shall be exploited.
- Multiplication represented by `*`. It has precedence of 7, and its associativity shall be exploited.
- Exponentiation represented by `^`. It has precedence of 8.
- Tetration represented by `^^`. It has precedence of 9.
- Pentation represented by `^^^`. It has precedence of 10.
- *ad infinitum*.

I was struggling for months to implement this with `ReadPrec`. It was truly a "Eureka" moment when I found that I have a workaround:

```
import Control.Monad
import Text.ParserCombinators.ReadPrec
import Text.Read
import Text.Read.Lex

hyperOp :: Int -> Integer -> Integer -> Integer
hyperOp 0 _ y = y + 1
hyperOp 1 x y = x + y
hyperOp 2 x y = x * y
hyperOp 3 x y = x ^ y
hyperOp n x 0 = 1
hyperOp n x y = hyperOp (n-1) x (hyperOp n x (y-1))

parseHyperOp :: Int -> ReadPrec Integer
parseHyperOp opn = parens . choice $
    lift readDecP
    : prec 6 (do
        m <- step (parseHyperOp opn)
        Symbol "+" <- lexP
        n <- parseHyperOp opn
        return (m + n))
    : prec 7 (do
        m <- step (parseHyperOp opn)
        Symbol "*" <- lexP
        n <- parseHyperOp opn
        return (m * n))
    : fmap (\c -> prec (7 + c) $ do
        m <- step (parseHyperOp opn)
        Symbol op <- lexP
        guard (replicate c '^' == op)
        n <- step (parseHyperOp opn)
        return (hyperOp (2 + c) m n)
        ) [1 .. opn]

highestOp :: String -> Int
highestOp "" = 0
highestOp ('^':str) = let
    (str1, str2) = span ('^'==) str
    in max (1 + length str1) (highestOp str2)
highestOp (_  :str) = highestOp str

parseOp :: Prec -> ReadS Integer
parseOp c str = readPrec_to_S (parseHyperOp (highestOp str)) c str
```

The trick is to find the highest operation within the input string. That makes the `choice` finite.

Still, I think it's quite ugly to use `readPrec_to_S`. Can this be implemented without using `readPrec_to_S` and co?

Comment: "Can this be implemented without using readPrec_to_S and co?" I would cheekily answer "remove the last two lines". Why are you using `ReadS` and what is "and co"? And are you aware that a common way to parse arithmetic expressions is to use a stack?

Comment: @Li-yaoXia `parseHyperOp` is just an auxiliary function for implementing `parseOp`, and is not to be used on its own. I tried implementing `parseOp` without using `readPrec_to_S` and `readS_to_Prec` because using them might cause potential runtime errors thereafter (say, by invoking `gather`). And I don't know whether Haskell *has* stacks.

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to **simply state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple rule of thumb is that you should never use `readS_to_Prec` and `readS_to_P`. Consider that once you've converted a parser to a `ReadS` to run it, there is no way back. (One handwavy explanation is that those functions are really dirty hacks, which is also why `gather` is undefined when they are used.)

Under those constraints, the only place where you can find out the maximal level `opn` of hyperoperators is at the very top level where you actually apply your parser to a string; that is the one location where you can scan the string to compute `opn`. That means that all your parsers need to be parameterized by `opn` in order to pass it down to `parseHyperOp`.

```hs
parseOp :: Int -> P.ReadP Integer
parseOp opn = readPrec_to_P (parseHyperOp opn) 0

-- Top-level runner for parsers parameterized by opn
runP :: (Int -> P.ReadP a) -> ReadS a
runP parser str =
  let opn = highestOp str in
  P.readP_to_S (parser opn) str

example = runP parseOp "(1 + 2) ^ 3 + 2 ^ 2"
```

Having an infinite number of precedence levels makes top-down parsing (the popular approach using parser combinators) rather problematic, since there isn't really a "top" to start from. Consider giving up that feature (by making all operators beyond a certain level non-associative at the same level), or switching to [a bottom-up parsing strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator-precedence_parser).